# Topics regrading linear space and tensor products

Tags: self-learning

To join a class, I have been asked by a professor to learn 
"linear space and its dual" 
"tensor products of vector spaces"

and the link to the book is

http://staff.math.su.se/mleites/books/prasolov-1994-problems.pdf
http://staff.math.su.se/mleites/books/2009-repr-theory-1.pdf

However, I am not sure which topics to cover (in the book) to have knowledge of the topics stated by professor.

Can somebody look into the content page of the above book and tell me which chapters should I read in order to learn the topics stated by the professor?

Comment: The table of contents is almost 8 pages alone.  Perhaps ask the professor?

Comment: I asked but I haven't received a reply. Just, maybe, check the main headings